# Elastic Beanstalk stack name in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I would like to ask you about defining stack name for Elastic Beanstalk in Cloudformation,  when I have define something like

```
  ResBeanstalkApplication:
Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
Properties:
  ApplicationName: !Ref ParaApplicationName
```

Stack name which is created on the list of stacks is totally random such as

**awseb-e-x6emimfusf-stack**

Application name is defined in parameters and it shows under Beanstalk page but on the cloudformation stack this has random name and additional to that it has separate stack but it should be nested...

do you know how to define in better way?